# Interval of convergence of series $\sum \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}x^n$ with knowledge of interval of $\sum a_n x^n$

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

I have to determine the interval of convergence of $\sum \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}x^n$ with the knowledge that $R=10$ for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n$.

I know that $\frac{1}{R}=\lim_{n \to \infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$ so I suppose I should use that to my advantage, however I am really not sure wheather this is even the right way of thinking. Any tips showing the right way to think about this one are very appreciated.

Comment: Also see my edit. I have added some more useful tips. The theorem I mentioned will often make things easier. I find it very useful.

Comment: **How** do you know that $\frac1R=\lim\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$??? If that was given, fine, but if you think that holds for all power series, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\displaystyle \frac{1}{R}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right\rvert=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert \frac{a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}}\right\rvert$ . We have By Ratio test that the series $\sum \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}x^n$ has radius of convergence $\frac{R}{R}=1$ . At $x=1$ it is clear that the series is $\sum \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$ whose nth term tends to $\frac{1}{R}$ which is finite and non-zero so the series diverges.(it also diverges for -1) So The interval of convergence is $(-1,1)$. Usually it is better to define the radius of convergence as $\displaystyle \frac{1}{R}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\text{sup}\sqrt[n]{a_{n}}$

(With this definition you will also get the same result but rather than calculating the limit of the raio, you are just computing the limit of the n-th root which is easier. There is something called Cauchy's  limit theorems which states that the limit of a convergent sequence equals the limit of the arithmetic mean of the terms of sequence and also equals the geometric mean. With a little manipulation , we can actually show that if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$ exists then it equals $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_{n}}$ .) which makes things easier

Comment: What makes you think that $1/R$ is that limit?

Comment: I just posted what the op said in his problem. I assumed that it was alreqdy given in his book. That is why I went for ratio test instead of cauchy-hadamard. And when he marked it as answer I obviously thought that I did not include anything which might have been not mentioned in his problem.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** What is the radius of convergence of this series?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{R}$$

Comment: Well honestly I am not really sure, but the very first thing that comes to mind is 1. But this is all kinda new to me and I am really rather guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say $$r_n=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}.$$The first question is where the claimed equality $$\frac1R=\lim r_n\quad(*)$$comes from. If this was given as part of the problem then you should ignore the rest of this answer.

But if $*$ was not given we should note that it's not necessarily true; obviously not, for example it could be that $a_n=0$ for infinitely many $n$. But even if we assume $a_n\ne0$ the radius of convergence of the original series does not determine the radius of convergence of $\sum r_nx^n$. For example if $a_n=1$ for all $n$ then $R=1$ and the radius of convergence of $\sum r_nx^n$ is $1$, while if $$a_n=\begin{cases} 1,&(n=2k),
\\2^{-n},&(n=2k+1)\end{cases}$$then $R=1$ but the radius of convergence of $\sum r_nx^n$ is $1/2$.